# Schedule Builds not adhering to CRON in Foundry

Tags: scheduler, palantir-foundry

Schedule has been set to update this table between 14th to 25th of every month Mon-Fri. Although, the build got triggered recently on 12th of August which shouldn't happen according to the specified CRON.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be a limitation of the cron expression, outside of Foundry - specifically this part:

> The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time. For example, ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.

So the cron schedule 30 8 14-25 * 1-5 will run between the 14th and 25th of the month and every Monday through Friday. (See for example crontab.guru (https://crontab.guru/#30_8_14-25_*_1-5).)

The generated description for it is not accurate, unfortunately we don't have much control over it as we use a library to turn the cron expressions into human readable expressions.

Related:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602328/are-the-day-of-month-and-day-of-week-crontab-fields-mutually-exclusive
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602216/when-will-an-interval-cron-execute-the-first-time-ex-3-days/602222#602222
- *https://blog.healthchecks.io/2022/09/schedule-cron-job-the-funky-way/*